# How to merge orders in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Does anyone know if combining/merging orders in Woocomerce is possible?

What I am trying to achieve is to give my customers the option to add more products in an existing order within a period of time (ex. 3 days)
If the customer has bought a product and the order has a set status (ex. processing) and then comes back to the site and adds up more products, then the orders will merge and they won't be charged additional shipping fees.

Is there a plugin for deferred orders, or something similar?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What about payment? How does price for shiping changes?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better suggestion which is scalable and doesn't have any unintended consequences.

During the checkout process, check to see if the user exists, if so, check for orders that are in process. If they customer has orders in process, then do no charge additional shipping if the shipping address is the same as their current order(s).

You will want to make this check again at the checkout process because they could leave their cart like that for any number of hours and if their processing order has been filled while their cart sits idle, you will have to eat the additional shipping charge.

A nice added feature would be tell them that their shipping is free and will be combined with their existing order.